# Guest mode in SpringBoot/Angular application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, authorization

I am working on developing a meal planner using Angular 10 + SpringBoot ver 2. The meal planner stores some user data on the backend such as - min and max nutrition requirements.

**Sample requirements:**

```
name        min     max     unitOfMeasure
'calories', 2000,   2400,   'cal'
'carbs',    105,    500,    'g'
'protein',  20,     200,    'g'
'fat',      5,      80,     'g'
'sodium',   30,     5000,   'mg'
'calcium',  100,    5000,   'mg'
```

I want the meal planner to work in 2 modes:

(1) **Login mode** - The user has customised the min max nutrition requirements

(2) **Guest mode** - Use the default min max requirements

I got the application working in login mode - the min max requirements is correctly retrieved from the DB. For guest mode, what is the recommended approach?

(1) Hardcode the nutrition requirements in a map and use it instead of reading from DB.

(2) Create a user 'guest' with default requirements. This will cause an issue because the password is set to be @NotBlank.

The min-max requirements will be used to formulate a meal plan for the user/guest.

Comment: If the min and max values is going to be same, then it is better to hardcode the values (if a registered user is not logged in) in the code itself, instead of fetching from data base. My extra suggestion, you can hardcode values default values for different guest age groups. Hope this helps. If not let me know.

Comment: Thankyou susil95, that sure helps. Pls post it as an answer. I would like to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the min and max values is going to be same, then it is better to hardcode the values (if a registered user is not logged in) in the code itself, instead of fetching from data base.

My extra suggestion, you can hardcode default values for different guest age groups.